# Using RewriteRule to make paths work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am running a web site on Apache. For the sake of friendly urls I use .htaccess file with a RewriteRule that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+) /newsarticles.php?pagenumber=$1 [NC,L]
```

This makes the link /news/3 lead to http://example.org/newsarticles.php?pagenumber=3

But now I have a path for different language, how can I make it work the same way for that path using a separate .htaccess file located in that paths folder?

For example I want /de/news/3 lead to http://example.org/de/newsarticles.php?pagenumber=3

I have tried the following, but it didnt work.

```
RewriteRule ^de/news/([^/]+) /de/newsarticles.php?pagenumber=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same htaccess file. you don't need to have one explicitly in that directory. Try your rules this way.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

#ignore real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^de/news/([^/]+)/? /de/newsarticles.php?pagenumber=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/? /newsarticles.php?pagenumber=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick and working answer.

Comment: Do I rewrite this the same way to get it working with /de?
`RewriteRule ^news/categories/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /news/newscategory.php?title=$1 [L]`

Comment: Yes just put de in front of the paths like the other rules.